# Weird used/free space view of network drives with Samba and XFS

Tags: windows, samba, quota, xfs

I'm using XFS project quotas to offer some private and limited disk space to my users, running Windows. It works pretty well, as the users can't exceed the quota like expected. However, the Samba's reported free/used disk space is a bit crazy. In "My computer", when the drive is just highlighted, the free space reported is the total amount of space of the server drive, and the used space is the amount of the quota. In the "Properties" of the network drive, it's worse, the used space information is a bunch of special characters and bytes values.

How can I set Samba up to send correct values to the Windows built-in SMB client?

Server: Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS with the default and latest packaged Samba version

Clients: Windows XP / Windows 7

Thanks.

Comment: I've used project quotas but never with Samba. Have you tried emailing the Samba/XFS mailing lists?

Comment: Someone already did last year: http://www.mail-archive.com/samba@lists.samba.org/msg99208.html but without success... Samba can be forced to show the values we want with "dfree command" but apparently, there's nothing for the used space information.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have quota information on xfs with samba, but you need to have the xfs quota libraries installed when you compile samba.